# How to center drawableTop and text vertically on the Button in Android?

Tags: xml, android, layout, button

I have the Button defined as follows:

```
<Button
 android:drawableTop="@drawable/ico"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:id="@+id/StartButton2x2"
 android:text="@string/Widget2x2StartBtnLabel"
 android:layout_width="0dip" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_weight="1" 
 android:background="@drawable/widgetbtn_bg"
/>
```

The problem is that 'drawableTop' image is aligned to the top border of the Button view. I would like to center it (together with text label) vertically on the button.

'android:gravity' seems to work only on text label. It does not affect 'drawableTop' positioning.

I was able to center it vertically using 'android:paddingTop' - but that does not seem to be a good idea. I guess it would not work properly on different screen resolution/size.

Comment: drawableTop, like its name suggests, always aligns the drawable to the top of the Button. Try drawableLeft instead, or if you want it behind the text, android:background.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**New answer**

Apparently I misunderstood the question. The answer is to use:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button">
```

...and enclose an `ImageView` and a `TextView` inside.

---

**Old answer**

Here's a thought: wrap your button in a FrameLayout. Soemthing like:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ico"
    android:foregroundGravity="center">
    <Button
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/StartButton2x2"
        android:text="@string/Widget2x2StartBtnLabel"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="@drawable/widgetbtn_bg" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Btw, what's up with `android:layout_width="0dip"`? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: This almost work. But the effect is a bit different - Now I have my label on top of my icon. I would like to have it below the icon, but both together centered on the button.

Comment: @Felix, you use `android:layout_width="0dp"` when using `android:layout_weight`. This tells Android to use the weights to figure out the size based on how much space is available in the enclosing layout.

Answer (score 9):

> 'android:gravity' seems to work only
>   on text label. It does not affect
>   'drawableTop' positioning.

Correct.

> I was able to center it vertically
>   using 'android:paddingTop' - but that
>   does not seem to be a good idea. I
>   guess it would not work properly on
>   different screen resolution/size.

You might be able to solve this by using dimension resources.

However, other than via padding, you cannot "center drawableTop and text vertically on the Button". The drawable feature of `Button` is not very configurable.

Comment: SO really needs a feature to +1 the answer for being correct, but -1 it for disliking the answer.

Comment: Using android:paddingTop in the button layout worked for me to center vertically the drawableTop. +1 for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use textview with its property.

```
<LinearLayout
            style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/.."
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/....."
  android:...............
  .......................
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

I was ok with it.

Answer (score -2):

Use `android:drawableTop="@drawable/Icon"` instead of background

Don't forget to change

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```